# Using last-modified and last-value in Sqoop Incremental Jobs

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

In sqoop, when we do incremental jobs, is it ok to use both last-value and last-modified arguments in one sqoop job.

Any answers?

Answer (score 0):

We generally use only either of the one. But if you want data sanctity then consider using both.